# How to combine array info

Tags: php, array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [week-day] => tuesday [day-date] => 1511841600 [events_ids] => Array ( [0] => 83417 ) ) 
    [1] => Array ( [week-day] => wednesday [day-date] => 1511913600 [events_ids] => Array ( [0] => 83417 ) ) 
    [2] => Array ( [week-day] => thrusday [day-date] => 1512000000 [events_ids] => Array ( [0] => 83417 ) ) 
    [3] => Array ( [week-day] => tuesday [day-date] => 1511830800 [events_ids] => Array ( [0] => 83411 ) ) 
)
```

How do I get the first value `tuesday` of key `week-day` and combine all `events_ids` of all tuesdays?

Comment: This kind of question would be best asked on stack overflow, as it isn't specific to WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get the desired result:

```
//Initial Array
$events = array
(
    array
    (
        'week-day' => 'tuesday',
        'day-date' => 1511841600,
        'events_ids' => array( 83417 )
    ),
    array
    (
        'week-day' => 'wednesday',
        'day-date' => 1511913600,
        'events_ids' => array( 83419, 12345 )
    ),
    array
    (
        'week-day' => 'tuesday',
        'day-date' => 1511830800,
        'events_ids' => array( 83411 )
    )
);

//Array to fill
$tuesday_event_ids = array();

foreach($events as $event ):

    //if day is tuesday & we have event IDs
    if($event['week-day'] === 'tuesday' && count($event['events_ids'])):
        foreach($event['events_ids'] as $id):

            //Push to array if not already in it
            if(!in_array($id,$tuesday_event_ids))
                array_push($tuesday_event_ids, $id);

        endforeach;
    endif;

endforeach;

//should be: array(83417,83411)
var_dump($tuesday_event_ids);
```

side note: you may want to consider changing the array keys to either be all `-` based or all `_` based for sanity.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy first unique weekday to the new array and then if that weekday repeats it will just add the events IDs.

```
$events = [
    [
        'week-day' => 'tuesday',
        'day-date' => 1511841600,
        'events_ids' => [83417]
    ],
    [
        'week-day' => 'wednesday',
        'day-date' => 1511913600,
        'events_ids' => [83417]
    ],
    [
        'week-day' => 'thrusday',
        'day-date' => 1512000000,
        'events_ids' => [83417]
    ],
    [
        'week-day' => 'tuesday',
        'day-date' => 1511830800,
        'events_ids' => [83417]
    ]
];

$new_events = [];

foreach ( $events as $event ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( $event['week-day'], $new_events ) ) {
        // If we have this week day just merge the event ids.
        $new_events[$event['week-day']]['events_ids'] = array_merge(
            $new_events[$event['week-day']]['events_ids'],
            $event['events_ids']
        );
    } else {
        $new_events[$event['week-day']] = $event;
    }
}

$new_events = array_values($new_events);
```

If the events in the initial array are not events just from one week you should focus on the `day-date` - associate all events IDs with it and then you can easily get the weekday name for that unique date. That approach would be much more versatile.